# jQuery UI Vertical Tabs makes page scroll "stick"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I am currently using the jQuery UI Vertical Tabs snippet out of the box, and there is a weird issue with how it affects the overall page scroll.  Every time you change the tab, then try to scroll up or down the page main page, it ends up "sticking" in place for a little bit then works as normal.  You  can see the effect here: http://investors.realcrowd.com/tab-tester

Not sure what the problem is or how even to diagnose it...Is there any snippet of code I can add to fix this?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Strange. Maybe eventPropagation?

Comment: Hmmm, can you explain further?  I am fairly new to jQuery, and my developer is unfamiliar with that term.  Really appreciate the quick response!

Comment: I'm not really a jQuery expert, and I actually think that it won't be easy to come up with a solution for that. It seems, to me, that the scroll event trigger is actually acting once you're clicking on a tab, but I'm not sure what the source is and how to solve it. Just a side note: did you notice that you're not including a file? you have an error in your page, maybe this can be related in any way to your problems? (your page is NOT including a stylesheet, if the stylesheet contains any class that needs to be applied it may be a reason). check this: http://prntscr.com/5cgfi4

Comment: Oh, I've got it sir. You have some kind of animations going on. Whenever you're clicking on a tab-element the document will scroll and set your view to the exact middle of the viewport. Not sure how you're calling it, but I'm quite confident that your files are missing something. Try to include the CSS above first. if you want the proof, try to click on a tab, WAIT 3 SECONDS and then scroll: it won't flick.

Comment: There you have it: there is the trigger that is making you swear: http://prntscr.com/5cgle4 just destroy the animation and you're done ;) Try removing this: `$('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);` From the very first script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure if that's the solution BUT, at such a point, I'm very confident it is.

Inspecting your source code, you have at the very beginning of your code a trigger. More specifically, it is located here:

```
<script>
$('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

Right after including jQuery.

In this code piece, you actually have an handler that fires whenever a non-empty anchor is called.
This event, after a few checks is going to call this:

```
$('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
```

Which is going to perform a 1 second animation (1000 milliseconds) that will scroll the view to the required target's top offset. In this second, if you're going to scroll, it is going to force you to be sticked at the top of the target's offset, therefore it will FORCE you to not scroll elsewhere but where he wants to.

To solve this, you can either set 1000 to 1, or just remove the animation, even if it's a good idea to actually scroll to the target's offset, therefore just replacing 1000 with 1 (or 10 or even 100) will be okay.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That did it!  Setting it to 1 did not seem to do anything, but removing the whole conditional fixed it.  Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it actually works in some of the ways proposed :P.